# select query inside select statement with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
select coa_ledgers.name, SUM($var1 - $var2) as amount
FROM entryitems
LEFT JOIN coa_ledgers
    ON entryitems.ledger_id = coa_ledgers.id
LEFT JOIN coa_groups
    ON coa_ledgers.group_id = coa_groups.id
where coa_groups.id = 13
group by coa_ledgers.id
```

In above $var1 should be `select SUM(entryitems.amount) where dc='D'` and $var2 should be `select SUM(entryitems.amount) where dc='C'`

Please help me to write this query, i am not sure if this need subquery.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `group by coa_ledgers.name`.

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN tables you don't select any columns from? Read [mcve], and make the question easier to understand.

Comment: main concern is i want to subtract value in $var1 and $var2 could anyone give me correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say where the `dc` is coming from, but you can do conditional sum:

```
select coa_ledgers.name, 
  SUM(if (dc='D', entryitems.amount, 0)) - SUM(if (dc='C', entryitems.amount, 0)) as amount
FROM entryitems
  LEFT JOIN coa_ledgers ON entryitems.ledger_id = coa_ledgers.id
  LEFT JOIN coa_groups ON coa_ledgers.group_id = coa_groups.id
where coa_groups.id = 13
group by coa_ledgers.id
```

Comment: dc is coming from entryitems

Comment: Then use that in the`if`. Another problem you have is that you are using `LEFT JOIN` with condition in `WHERE`. This will turn the `LEFT JOIN` to a normal join. Just use `JOIN` or move the condition after the `ON`.